# How to pass list to argparse.ArgumentParser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have an `argparse.ArgumentParser()` object, reading directly from `sys.argv`. I'd like to override the list at some places, and pass the argument list directly to `ArgumentParser()`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_args = sys.argv
# do something to my_args
# ...
parser.parse_args(my_args)
```